# What is different between Set and Type in Coq?

Tags: dependent-types, coq

AFAIU types can be a `Set` whose elements are programs or a `proposition` whose elements are Proofs. So based on this understanding:

```
Inductive prod (X Y: Type) : Set := 
| pair: X -> Y -> prod X Y.
```

Following code should compile but it does not due to the following error. If I change `Set` with `Type` or the other `Type` with `Set` it compiles fine. Can someone help me understand what the following error means? I am trying to teach myself Coq using Software Foundations book.

Error:

```
Error: Large non-propositional inductive types must be in Type.
```

Comment: Theorem provers have always been a grey area for CS.SE, but I'm guessing this is a good candidate for mods to migrate to StackOverflow.

Comment: This question has some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601502/what-exactly-is-a-set-in-coq).

Comment: @jmite Given that this question is about the calculus of constructions with Coq just serving as the concrete syntax, I think it's on-topic here.

Answer (score 19):

Coq has 4 "big" types:

- `Prop` is meant for propositions. It is impredicative, meaning that you can instantiate polymorphic functions with polymorphic types. It is also erased at run-time, meaning you can't pattern match on a Prop value to build a Type value, unless there's only one possibility.
- `SProp` is like Prop, but with definitional proof irrelevance, meaning that if $p_1, p_2 : P$ then $p_1 = p_2$.
- `Set` is meant for computation. It's predicative, and doesn't have proof irrelevance, which lets you do nice things like not assuming $1 = 2$. The `Set` parts remain during code extraction.
- `Type` is a supertype of both of these, allowing you to write code once that works with either

I'm pretty sure your error is because you're defining a `Set` whose parameters can be `Type`, which means they can be `Prop`, which isn't allowed. If you change to this:

```
Inductive prod (X Y: Set) : Set := 
| pair: X -> Y -> prod X Y.
```

your code should work.

EDIT: Updated to include SProp.

Comment: Coq does not have proof irrelevance for `Prop` unless you add it as an axiom.

Comment: @Geoff My mistake, updated to reflect this.